# Is this gross misconduct?

Tags: contracts, contracting, mistakes, dismissal

I left a role in 2017 but due to a resignation before I left I asked the director if I can put it down as a contract. He said I could as I was advised by a career advisor.

I am based in a country where recordings about social contributions and the like can be accessed: these contributions shows I was an employee of that company, contrarily to what I agreed with the former director and what I wrote in my CV.

Fast forward to 2023 and the company has dissolved and been acquired by another company which does not have my records I am worried about this due to the fact that my current employer’s CV I put it down as a contract.

My question is this gross misconduct could I get fired for this?

I am really worried now.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147007/discussion-on-question-by-sas121-is-this-gross-misconduct); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you get fired for this? Probably, you knowingly and deliberately lied on your CV.

*Will* you get fired for specifically this? Unlikely, it was 6 years ago.

Could it be used as a reason to fire you if the company was looking to get rid of you anyway? Probably.

tl;dr: lying is bad. Don't do it.

Comment: I didn’t knowingly lie on my cv I thought you could do this as a norm

Comment: If I want to go to another company how do I deal with this?

Comment: @Sas121 - You thought you could put something that wasn't actually true?  You either were a contract worker or you were not a contract worker.  If you were a contract worker then you should have paperwork to prove that fact.

Comment: I don’t have paperwork to prove it

Comment: The biggest red flag I'm seeing here is that *you are still trying to justify your behaviour*. It seems you haven't learnt anything from that mistake.

Comment: I have learnt but I am trying to find a way to move in from this

Comment: With all due respect: you don't seem to have learnt. You are still making excuses for your behaviour.

Comment: I know it was wrong of me to do this and I do regret what do you think I should from here?

Comment: @Sas121 - Update your resume so it’s accurate. Accept the fallback for not having an accurate resume. Congressman, CEOs, have all had issues years later for not telling the truth about their work experience. It doesn’t matter if you lied yesterday or 6 years. You still lied on your resume

Comment: What do you mean by fallback? Could I get fired?

Comment: Which bit of "Could you get fired for this? Probably" is not clear to you?

Comment: What shall I tell my current employer?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts is that it wouldn't be Gross Misconduct.

Now - if I go to Ye Olde Google and pull up 'Gross Misconduct' - there's a few websites with a list - here's one of them:

- Theft or fraud
- Physical violence or bullying
- Damage to property
- Serious insubordination
- Serious safety and health regulations breaches
- Establishing a competing business
- Discrimination or harassment
- Wrong use of an organization's property or name
- Bribing or accepting bribes
- Leaking company information or causing a serious breach
- Breach of confidence

Granted this is not an exhaustive list - but I'm including it to make the point - if we take what has happened in the worst possible light: Lying on your CV (not saying you have lied, just saying the worst way it could be interpreted) - that in-of-itself does not rise to any of these scenarios. If you had falsely claimed to have Degrees that you didn't have, then that could be considered fraud - but that is not what has happened here.

The question is around the nature of your employment - were you a direct employee or a Contractor. In terms of a CV, that isn't a major issue - as what someone will care more about is what you did while employed, rather than the exact type of employment.

If there are missing records or there's a degree of uncertainty, then that should work in your favor. Additionally - if you can't find your original contract, depending on your region you could look at other factors to 'prove' your contractor status - does their payroll system show you as having any employee benefits (Sick Leave/PTO etc.) does their accounting system show that you are paid from a separate budget? Do you pay your own taxes or are they paid directly when you are paid by the company?

All those little details could be used to clarify your status if there is a dispute.

However the one thing I will add is this - if you have been working with a company for 6 years, any dispute about what's on your CV is probably null and void at this point.

Comment: My hmrc records show me as a direct employer of the company what do I do if apply for another job with another company or a promotion

Comment: @Sas121 - I'd just update my CV to match the HMRC records then. I doubt anyone would cross-check or find out. If it really bothers you - you could put a note in your cover letter saying that when you joined, a Director indicated you were a contractor, but after organizational changes, it appears you've been made an employee.

Comment: But this not gross misconduct or something that can get me fired